# Can view the history of powershell OUTPUTS?

Tags: windows, powershell

It is easy to view the command history of powershell, but sometimes, one might forget to record some important output of the commands, and wish to have a look back into what was on the screen?

Is the history of **outputs** automatically saved somewhere?

Answer (score 9):

By default, PowerShell records history of commands, but not their output.

You can request PowerShell to record screen output into a file. Use `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript` for this.

**Example**

```
Start-Transcript

'do stuff here'
Get-Service X*
'do some more stuff here'

Stop-Transcript
```

If you want PowerShell to automatically record all your stuff every time, you can add `Start-Transcript` in your PowerShell profile (use $PROFILE system variable to find path to your profile script, then add `Start-Transcript` into it)

By default, a new text file is created every time you start transcript. If you want to keep adding output into the same file, then `Start-Transcript -Path C:\ExistingTranscript.txt -Append`

Comment: Of course, from a security standpoint this should be highly discouraged, as passwords and other secrets could end up sitting in some plaintext file on the drive (and then maybe even synced to the cloud and other machines) ...

Answer (score 0):

To automatically run the `Start-Transcript` to save outputs:

The path and file represented by the `$PROFILE` system variable are not created on my computer.  To create this path and file, run the following command.

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path $PROFILE)) {
  New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PROFILE -Force
}
```

Then run `notepad $PROFILE`.
Then paste the `Start-Transcript` into the file (For me is ...\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1)

Comment: See my comment above - this is probably unwise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71099275/can-view-the-history-of-powershell-outputs#comment136863830_71099385